# Call method of shared-library with 2 different signatures (unknown target-system)

Tags: c, overloading

In my program, I'm using a method of a shared library.

My program is compiled for hundred of thousand different devices (Android) and I'm not able to provide specific binaries for each target-system.

The method of the shared-library on the target-devices can sadly have 2 different signatures:

**System A**

```
int (*open_output_stream)(
    struct audio_hw_device *dev, // equal on all systems 
    audio_io_handle_t handle, // unimportant 
    audio_devices_t devices, // unimportant 
    audio_output_flags_t flags, // unimportant 
    struct audio_config *config, // unimportant 
    struct audio_stream_out **stream_out // equal on all systems
);
```

**System B**

```
int (*open_output_stream)(
    struct audio_hw_device *dev, // equal on all systems 
    uint32_t devices, // unimportant
    int *format, // unimportant 
    uint32_t *channels, // unimportant 
    uint32_t *sample_rate, // unimportant 
    struct audio_stream_out **out // equal on all systems
);
```

In my code I need to call that method with the first param (**struct audio_hw_device**) and the last param (**struct audio_stream_out**) to get the result I need.

The other 4 params between are not important for me and I would replace them by 0 or NULL.

Who can tell me if I can just call those methods like

audio_hw_device_t *outHwDev

```
int res = open_output_stream)(
    outHwDev, // equal on all systems 
    NULL or 0 ?, // unimportant
    NULL or 0 ?, // unimportant 
    NULL or 0 ?, // unimportant 
    NULL or 0 ?, // unimportant 
    &outStream // equal on all systems
);
```

or is something like a "try{callFunction}(catch UnknownMethodException){}" possible in C:? :)

There is no official header-file for this, I have to define it by myself but that should matter here.

Comment: Fortunately `NULL` is equal to `0` on most platforms, so it should not matter. You might get compiler warnings though.

Comment: If it's just a warning then that would be acceptable for me (but hardly). But I have to go sure that I wont get an exception due to invalid signature later. There's nothing like try-catch in C, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to detect which system you are running on? If so you could provide a wrapper in your own code:

```
int systema_open_output_stream(
    struct audio_hw_device *dev, 
    struct audio_stream_out **out
)
{
    audio_io_handle_t handle; // unimportant 
    audio_devices_t devices; // unimportant 
    audio_output_flags_t flags; // unimportant 
    struct audio_config *config; // unimportant

    return open_output_stream_a(dev, handle, devices, flags, config, out)
}

int systemb_output_stream(struct audio_hw_device *dev,
    struct audio_stream_out **out
)
{
    uint32_t devices; // unimportant
    int *format; // unimportant 
    uint32_t *channels; // unimportant 
    uint32_t *sample_rate; // unimportant

    return open_output_stream_b(dev, devices, format, channels, sample_rate, out);
}

if (is_system_a())
     out_func = &systema_output_stream;
else
     out_func = &systemb_output_stream;

int res = out_func(dev, out);
```